# tail -f produces no output in Ubuntu live CD

Tags: livecd, tail, inotify, overlayfs

For some test I start Ubuntu Live from USB.

I'm trying to use *tail* command to show debug log, but it doesn't work.

I also test opening two terminals (`t1`, `t2`) with this code:

`t1`:

```
touch a
```

`t2`:

```
tail -f a
```

`t1`:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do echo $i >> a; sleep 1; done
```

Nothing in `t2`! What can be the cause?

Comment: You are using a relative path. Is `$PWD` the same in both terminals?

Comment: same..if after echo in t1 I do 'cat a' in t2, I can see the appended string.. I can't undertand..

Comment: I used ``watch -n 0.1 tail -n 50 filename.log`` as a workaround

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's a case of `tail` not working at all, then it could be because your liveCD is using the `overlayfs` filesystem, which has a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/882147) regarding notifications of modified files.  You could try to move the log to another filesystem, such as `/tmp` if the application creating the log has an option to do so.

You could also carry out your test in `/tmp` instead of your homedir.